# Calculating percent from winning time in data frame of race results for elite athletes

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I created a data frame of race results for elite Alpine Skiers across all the world cup races over a four year period.  I am using dplyr and have grouped the races by the Race ID, arranged the race results by the athlete placing in ascending order (first to last), and converted the finish time into Minutes.

I now want to create a new variable called Percent.From.Winning.Time that would make each finish time relative to the winning time for that specific race (i.e. the first place finisher ends up with a value of 100, and the rest have a percent of winning time of less than 100).  For example, suppose the winning time for a given race was 120 s and the second place finisher had a time of 121 s.  I would calculate: [1 - ((121-120)/120)] * 100 = 99.16.

Please note that I've also designated a non-finish time (e.g. athlete got disqualified or did not finish) as NA.

Here is some sample data:

```
Raceid=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Athleteid=c(45, 21, 56, 64, 10, 76, 88, 91, 23, 13, 123, 2, 87, 91)
Position = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA)
Timetot3= c(144, 143, 142, 141, 140, NA, NA, 123, 122, 121, 120, NA, NA, NA)
WC.race.results=cbind(Raceid, Athleteid, Position, Timetot3)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion or a solution on how I can write a function in dplyr to generate this new variable Percent.From.Winning.Time?

Thank you very much for your consideration.

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with dplyr would be;

```
group_by(mydf, Raceid) %>%
mutate(Percent = (1 - (Timetot3 - min(Timetot3, na.rm = TRUE)) / min(Timetot3, na.rm = TRUE)) * 100)

#   Raceid Athleteid Position Timetot3   Percent
#1       1        45        1      144  97.14286
#2       1        21        2      143  97.85714
#3       1        56        3      142  98.57143
#4       1        64        4      141  99.28571
#5       1        10        5      140 100.00000
#6       1        76       NA       NA        NA
#7       1        88       NA       NA        NA
#8       2        91        1      123  97.50000
#9       2        23        2      122  98.33333
#10      2        13        3      121  99.16667
#11      2       123        4      120 100.00000
#12      2         2       NA       NA        NA
#13      2        87       NA       NA        NA
#14      2        91       NA       NA        NA
```

DATA

```
mydf <- data.frame(Raceid=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                   Athleteid=c(45, 21, 56, 64, 10, 76, 88, 91, 23, 13, 123, 2, 87, 91),
                   Position = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA),
                   Timetot3= c(144, 143, 142, 141, 140, NA, NA, 123, 122, 121, 120, NA, NA, NA))
```

Comment: This solution worked very well.  It was easy to employ as I was building tables using various dplyr functions. If you are working with in dplyr this will be a nice way to calculate this type of performance metrics.

Answer (score 3):

Here a `data.table` solution :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(WC.race.results)[
        ,wt:=(1-(Timetot3-in(Timetot3,na.rm=TRUE))/min(Timetot3,na.rm=TRUE))*100,
        Raceid]

#    Raceid Athleteid Position Timetot3        wt
# 1:      1        45        1      144  97.14286
# 2:      1        21        2      143  97.85714
# 3:      1        56        3      142  98.57143
# 4:      1        64        4      141  99.28571
# 5:      1        10        5      140 100.00000
# 6:      1        76       NA       NA        NA
# 7:      1        88       NA       NA        NA
# 8:      2        91        1      123  97.50000
# 9:      2        23        2      122  98.33333
# 10:     2        13        3      121  99.16667
# 11:     2       123        4      120 100.00000
# 12:     2         2       NA       NA        NA
# 13:     2        87       NA       NA        NA
# 14:     2        91       NA       NA        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **much longer** but at least package-free solution:

```
WC.race.results=data.frame(Raceid, Athleteid, Position, Timetot3)    
results.split <- by(WC.race.results, WC.race.results$Raceid, function(race) {
  win <- min(race$Timetot3, na.rm=TRUE)
  cbind(race, wt=(1-((race$Timetot3-win)/race$Timetot3))*100)
})
WC.race.results <- do.call(rbind, results.split)
```

I'm pretty sure there's a way to improve this, maybe using `dplyr` itself, but it's a start I guess.

**Edit:**

There's already a `dplyr` answer, I'll leave mine for the sake of it anyway.

Comment: `lapply`-ing on `split` data is equivalent to `by`

Comment: I was not familiar with that, thanks.Should I just use `by(WC.race.results, WC.race.results$Raceid, function(race)...`?